# How do you read tab delimited strings from a txt file and put them into variables?

Tags: c, file

I have a file that I'm trying to read and fill variables with.  The file consists of this:

```
0\ttake a nap\n
1\tstudy heap-based priority queue\n
101\treview trees for Midterm 2\n
3\tdo assignment 7\n
```

This may be hard to read, but you can see that there is an integer to begin with, followed by a tab, a string after that, followed by a newline.  I need to take the integer and put that into a variable, detect the tab, and put the string following the tab into a variable, detect the newline, take the two variables and create a node with the information, and then start over again on the next line.  After hours of scouring the internet, this is what I've come up with:

```
char activity[SIZE];
 char position[SIZE];
 char line[100];

  FILE *infile;
  char *inname = "todo.txt";

  int i = 0;


  infile = fopen(inname, "r");
  if (!infile) {
    printf("Couldn't open %s for reading\n");
    return 0;
  }
while(i < 100 && fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile) != NULL){
        sscanf(line, "%s\t%s", position, activity);
        printf("%s\n", position);
        printf("%s\n", activity);
        i++;
    }
```

When running this test code on the txt file above, I get this as a result:

```
0
take
1
study
101
review
3
do
```

So, it looks to me like it's getting the first number alright (as a string) and putting it into the variable, seeing the tab, and grabbing the first sequence after the tab and stopping there after putting it into the other variable.  How do I rectify this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try changing the `sscanf`:

```
sscanf(line, "%s\t%[^\n]", position, activity);
```

The `%s` specifier stops when it encounters blanks. That's why it only reads *study* instead of *study heap-based priority queue*. The `%[^\n]` tells it: "read until newline". Another issue: you should test the value returned by `sscanf` to make sure it filled the required number of objects.

---

You could also read the first integer as an integer, changing `position` to `int` and using `%d` instead of `%s`.

#### EDIT

To make myself clear, what I was suggesting was:

```
int position;
sscanf(line, "%d\t%[^\n]", &position, activity);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that with position and it just ended up giving me the address of the variable position (ie. like 1003020010) I will try your other suggestions.

Comment: @FeralShadow Strange. Did you also change `position` to `&position` in `sscanf` ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.  If i change the %s to a %d within the printf statement, it gives me the memory address.  If i change type of position to int, and leave the printf as %s, it gives me the number I need. In addition, I changed the sscanf to %d for the position as well, so it really seems like it needs to be read in as a string?

Comment: At any rate your suggestion about the %[^\n] worked perfectly.  I'll find a way to convert the position string to an integer.

Comment: @FeralShadow I'm glad it worked :-) See my edit; if that doesn't work, there's always `strtoul`.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked quite well for my use case.  I wanted to read the first two fields of a TAB-delimited file into string vars, then read the remainder of each line into a final string var.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned char     string1 [255];
   unsigned char     string2 [255];
   unsigned char     string3 [255];

   /* read from stdin until done */
   while(!feof(stdin))
   {
      fscanf( stdin, "%[^\t]\t%[^\t]\t%[^\n]\n", string1, string2, string3 );
      printf( "%s\t%s\t%s\n",                    string1, string2, string3 );
   }

   return(0);
}
```

I'm reading from STDIN because I used this program to create a command line filter.

Explanation of the fscanf codes:

```
%[^\t] - any character that is not a TAB
\t     - the TAB character
%[^\n] - any character that is not a NEWLINE
\n     - the NEWLINE character
```

Thus, my fscanf is reading all characters up to the first TAB (including spaces but not the TAB itself) and placing the string into var string1, all characters up to the second TAB (including spaces but not the TAB itself) and placing the string into var string2, then reading all remaining characters of the record (TABs, spaces, everything except the NEWLINE) up to the NEWLINE into string3.

In my real program, I am doing specific processing on string1 and string2.  My output is the result of that processing along with string3.  In other words, my output is also TAB-delimited with the original contents of string3 unaltered.

If you have a TAB-delimited file with three or more fields, then the following (on Linux) should be true:

```
cat FILE | ABOVE_PROGRAM > OUT_FILE
diff FILE OUT_FILE       # This should yield nothing (no differences)
```

Hopefully this will help others process TAB-delimited files.