# How to write and read (including spaces) from text file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, printf

I'm using `fscanf` and `fprintf`.

I tried to delimit the strings on each line by `\t` and to read it like so:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d\t%s\t%s",&t->num,&t->string1,&t->string2);
```

The file contents:

```
1[TAB]string1[TAB]some string[NEWLINE]
```

It does not read properly. If I `printf("%d %s %s",t->num,t->string1,t->string2)` I get:

```
1 string1 some
```

Also I get this compile warning:

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[15]' [-Wformat]
```

How can I fix this without using binary r/w?

Comment: "It does not read properly". What *does* "it" do? And did you properly allocate whatever `t` is pointing to (assuming the members of the structure it is typed to be are also proper)?

Comment: I'll edit my question, one moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the space in `"some string"` is the problem. `fscanf()` reading a string using `%s` stops at the first whitespace character. To include spaces, use something like:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d\t%[^\n\t]\t%[^\n\t]", &t->num, &t->string1, &t->string2);
```

See also [a reference page for `fscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) and/or [another StackOverflow thread on reading tab-delimited items in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908668/how-do-you-read-tab-delimited-strings-from-a-txt-file-and-put-them-into-variable).

[EDIT in response to your edit: You seem to also have a problem with the arguments you're passing into `fscanf()`. You will need to post the declarations of `t->string1` to be sure, but it looks like `string1` is an array of characters, and therefore you should remove the `&` from the `fscanf()` call...]

Comment: Buffer overflow. You cannot read in arbitrary-lengthed strings like that. How should `fscanf` know the size of the objects pointed to by `t->string1` and `t->string2` (the error message looks like the `&` are wrong)?

Comment: what is your suggestion to prevent overflowing?

Comment: @MikeL If you can't guarantee a maximum size for the input string(s) and allocate your buffer accordingly, you can [use width specifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787892/overflow-over-scanf8s-string) to enforce a maximum field length. I should have included that in the answer but it wasn't the topic of the question so I glossed over it.

Answer (score 3):

The `%s` conversion specification stops reading at the first white space, and tabs and blanks both count as white space.

If you want to read a string of non-tabs, you can use a 'scan set' conversion specifier:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%[^\t\n]\t%[^\t\n]", &t->num, t->string1, t->string2) != 3)
    ...oops - format error in input data...
```

(I'd lay odds that omitting the `&` from the string arguments is correct.)  *The question was edited; I win. Dropping the `&` is necessary to avoid the compiler warning!*

This still doesn't quite do what you expect. If there are blanks at the start of the second field, they'll be eaten by the `\t` in the format string. Any white space in the format string eats any white space (including newlines) in the input.  The `%[^\t]` conversion specification won't get started until there's a character that isn't white space in the input.  I'm also assuming you want your input limited by newlines.  You can leave out the `\n` characters if you prefer.

Note that I checked that the `fscanf()` interpreted 3 fields.  It is important to error check your inputs.

If you really want control, you should probably read whole lines with `fgets()` and then use `sscanf()` to parse the data.

---

> About `fgets()` and `sscanf()`; can you expand about how it will give more control?

Suppose the input data is written

```
1234



a string with spaces



another string
```

spread out over multiple lines like that.  With raw `fscanf()`, this will be acceptable input even though it is spread over 9 lines of input.  With `fgets()`, you can read a single line, and then analyze it with `sscanf()`, and you'll know that the first line was not in the correct format.  You can then decide what to do about it.

Also, since [mafso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741125/mafso) called me on it in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803245/how-to-write-and-read-including-spaces-from-text-file/20803374?noredirect=1#comment31189462_20803374), we should ensure that there are no buffer overflows by limiting the size of the strings that the scan sets match.

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%14[^\t\n]\t%14[^\t\n]", &t->num, t->string1, t->string2) != 3)
    ...oops - format error in input data...
```

I'm using the error message about `char (*)[15]` to deduce that 14 is the correct number to use.  Note that unlike `printf()`, you can't specify the sizes via `*` notation (in the `scanf()`-family, `*` supresses assignment), so you have to create the format with the correct sizes.  Further, the size you specify is the number of characters before the terminating null byte, so if the array is of size 15, the size you specify in the format string is 14, as shown.

Comment: Your overflowing buffers with your `fscanf` call.

Comment: Yes, no...I'm not, but I'm not making sure they aren't overflowed.  Without definitions of the string types, it was hard to know what values to use — though once the question was updated, you could guess that `%14[\t\n]` was probably appropriate.

Comment: removing & fixed the problem, Jonathan about fgets() and sscanf() can you expand about how it will give more control?