# how to read data from a file with space ignored?

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have this piece of program that I use to read data from file:

```
void baca(int *n)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("namafile.txt", "r");
    if (f)
    {
        while (fscanf(f, "%[^|]|%d|%[^\n]\n", mhs[*n].nama, &mhs[*n].umur, mhs[*n].hp)==3)
        {
            (*n)++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

If I write the data in the file like this, then the program reads it correctly:

```
nko|20|9999

hotma|21|9982882

andi|30|212313
```

But when I add some spaces like this, somehow it doesn't read it correctly:

```
nko | 20 | 9999

hotma | 21 | 9982882

andi | 30 | 212313
```

Can someone give me some hint on what I should do ?

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803245/how-to-write-and-read-including-spaces-from-text-file) link and see it can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a space to the format string to specify where the input can have optional whitespace

```
fscanf(f, "%[^|] |%d | %[^\n]\n", ...)
//             ^^^ ^^^^^   optional whitespace
```

The conversion `"%d"` already includes optional leading whitespace.

*<sub>If your input strings can get messier in the future, you will do better with a separate parser instead of `scanf()`.</sub>*